# use dhcp on eth0 using command line

Tags: ip, dhcp

I am trying to set the `eth0` interface to use dhcp to get an ipv4 address, using the command line. I can manually change the ip address using

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 x.x.x.x netmask x.x.x.x
```

Is there a similar command to use to set `eth0` to get an address using dhcp? I tried typing:

```
sudo dhclient eth0
```

however the ip address doesn't change when I type this. The  `/etc/network/interfaces` file was set to

```
iface eth0 inet manual
```

which I then changed to:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

however this doesn't change the `eth0` ip address even if the system is rebooted.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If your `dhcp` is properly configured to give you an IP address, the command:

```
dhclient eth0 -v
```

should work. The option `-v` enable verbose log messages, it can be useful.

If your `eth0` is already up, before asking for a new IP address, try to deconfigure `eth0`.

To configure the network interfaces based on interface definitions in the file `/etc/network/interfaces` you can use `ifup` and `ifdown` commands.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to run the following command:

```
dhclient -v -r
```

Then change the `ip` adress:

```
ifconfig eth0 xx.xx.xx.xx
```

Change `xx.xx.xx.xx` with the needed ip_adress